# Complications of using this in a nested function, how can I refactor?

Tags: typescript

I'm using a third party library that requires a pair of formatting functions to be held inside an object which is then passed around. The problem is that with the current way the functions are written I am unable to access the class fields due to the nested function changing the lexical scope of the `this` keyword.

```
this.formatOptions = {
      to: function (value) {
        return Math.round(value) + this.unitCharacter; //this.uniCharacter is inaccessible from these functions 
      },
      from: function (value) {
        return Math.round(value);
      }
    }
```

I've rewrote the function as a class method, like the below. However I can't figure out how to refactor the above to make use of the new method.

```
formatFunction = (value) => {
    return Math.round(value) + this.unitCharacter;
  }
```

I want to do something like:

```
this.formatOptions = {
      to: this.formatFunction(value);
      from: this.formatFunction(value);
    }
```

But this doesn't work, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use a currying function to create your `to` function ahead of time.

```
const createToFormatter = (unitCharacter:string) => {
   return (value:number) => {
       return `${Math.round(value)}${unitCharacter}`
   }
}
```

then you could prepare your formatting methods like this:

```
this.formatOptions = {
   to: createToFormatter(this.unitCharacter),
   from: (value:number) => {
       return Math.round(value);
   }
}
```

`createToFormatter` allows you to build the formatter function in your class scope where `this` is indeed your class. But now you are passing `unitCharacter` as a value to the currying function, and it returns a format function that no longer requires a reference to `this`, because it now has it's own copy of the `unitCharacter` value.

Your `from` function appears to be a simple pure function, so I think that can be used as is.